# Что означает ":" в структуре C++?

Tags: c++, struct

Смотрел один код с гитхаба и наткнулся на вот такую структуру:

```
struct vec2
{
    float x, y;
    vec2(float value) : x(value), y(value) {}
    vec2(float _x, float _y) : x(_x), y(_y) {}
};
```

Изучаю C++ не так давно, поясните, пожалуйста, что значат 4 и 5 строчки.

Comment: Два конструктора для создания объекта типа `vec2` из соответственно одного и двух значений типа `float`...

Comment: После двоеточия можно написать конструкторы полей через запятую. Во втором конструкторе подчёркивания не нужны: `x(x)` сконструирует поле `x` из параметра `x`. Компилятор знает что это два разных икса.

Comment: Спасибо всем!! Очень помогли.

Answer (score -1):

: в C++ это что-то в роде сокращения кода. Есть исключения конечно. В методах/функциях : означает присваивание из параметров. Работает это так:

```
size_t globalvar = 0; // Переменная в которую сохраняем значение
void myfunc(size_t otherValue) : /*Тут вставляем имя переменной в которую сохраним значение*/globalvar(/*Суда пишем параметр*/otherValue) {}
```

Но не всегда это сокращение. Например : так же используется для наследования в классах/структурах

И ещё, эти присваивания можно писать через запятую

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Что тут сделано не так? https://ideone.com/yWlC9j - в функции использовано `:`? )) Вы так и не поняли, что это инициализация в КОНСТРУКТОРЕ.

Comment: Я писал это вечером и хотел спать. Ну в своё оправдание могу сказать, что в самом предложении я не упоминал код в вопросе. Я упоминал лишь методы и функции, потому я всё правильно написал) @Mikhailo